# Is there something called array of list?

Tags: c#, arrays, list

I declared something like this

```
List<double> close = new List<double>();
```

I pass this list to a function XYZ and the function will fill it up with value. As I need to run this XYZ function many times, is there a way to create a array of list so that I can access the third list element 7 by typing `listarray[2][6]`.

Comment: what language are we talking about here?

Comment: sorry I am new to this forum and I do not know this is not C# exclusive. I am using c#.

Comment: List<double>[] arrayOfLists = new List<double>[sizeOfTheArray];

Comment: Do you know the size of array?

Answer (score 3):

I think you need something like this:

```
List<List<double>> list = new List<List<double>>();

var list1 = new List<double>();
list1.Add(1);
list1.Add(2);

var list2 = new List<double>();
list2.Add(3);
list2.Add(4);

list.Add(list1);
list.Add(list2);

var element = list[1][1];
```

The value of element will be the element of the second list at index of 1. 
In this case, 4.

Answer (score 1):

Thats about it:

```
List<double>[] arrayOfLists = new List<double>[200];
arrayOfLists[0] = new List<double>();

arrayOfLists[0].Add(5);

Console.WriteLine(arrayOfLists[0][0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, just make either an array of lists (if you want it fixed sized), or a list of lists.

```
List<List<double>> items = new List<List<double>>();

List<double> close = new List<double>()

items.Add(close); //close is now element 0 in the outer list.

close.Add(1.23);

double result = items[0][0]; //result now equals 1.23
```